# Variable in php echo

Tags: php, syntax

I would really need help with a primitive thing.

I need this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[cycloneslider id="<?php $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
echo $my_meta['odkaz']; ?>"]'); ?>
```

I do not know how exactly do it.
I made it by this solution:

```
   <?php $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);?> 
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[cycloneslider id="'.$my_meta['odkaz'].' "]'); ?>
```

Is it right or..Could you edit it to right way?

Comment: You can't nest `<?php  ?>` tags. Your second attempt is the right way, although as a matter of style you don't need to open and close your `<?php ?>` tags on every line - just open before the first line and close after the last will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't see clear your own code.
If that happens, then adopt a more verbose way of programming and create variables that describe more the values:

```
<?php 

$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
$idCycloneSlider = $my_meta['odkaz'];
$doShortCodeResult = do_shortcode('[cycloneslider id="'.$idCycloneSlider.'"]');
echo $doShortCodeResult; 

?>
```

That way we see clearly what happens in each line and the string concatenation is more simple to do.

Comment: Even nicer solution. I will use this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it using a [string interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php):

```
<?php 
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
    echo do_shortcode("[cycloneslider id=\"{$my_meta['odkaz']}\"]"); 
?>
```

Or using a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) if extra spaces are ok:

```
<?php 
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
    $shortcode = <<<TEXT
[cycloneslider id="{$my_meta['odkaz']}"]
TEXT;
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate string and variables with the `.` operator:

```
$var = "Hello, I am made up of " . $some . $variables . " and strings";
```